# SQLite Combine Multiple Queries With Shared Column

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I am trying to write a SQLite query that gets the total occurrences of a value, divided by months.

An example of the desired output:

```
Name   Jun  Jul  Aug  Sept
John   3    2    5    2
Robert 4    12   45   22
Linda  0    2    1    0
```

I want the `Name` field to only return unique results, so it will basically count every time "John" appeared in the month of Jun, Jul, etc.

Here is what I have so far, using my actual DB. It works to return the right columns and unique "ReasonDetail" but the counts are not accurate:

```
SELECT * FROM

(
    SELECT ReasonDetail AS Appetite, COUNT(*) AS June
        FROM CallRecords
        WHERE CallReason = 'Appetite Question'
        AND DateTime BETWEEN  '2017-06-01 00:00' AND '2017-07-01 00:00'
        GROUP BY ReasonDetail
),
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS July
        FROM CallRecords
        WHERE CallReason = 'Appetite Question'
        AND DateTime BETWEEN  '2017-07-01 00:00' AND '2017-08-01 00:00'
        GROUP BY ReasonDetail
),
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS August
        FROM CallRecords
        WHERE CallReason = 'Appetite Question'
        AND DateTime BETWEEN  '2017-08-01 00:00' AND '2017-09-01 00:00'
        GROUP BY ReasonDetail
)
GROUP BY Appetite
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to compile the proper counts in this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation. Use `case` expressions in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT ReasonDetail AS Appetite
,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateTime>='2017-06-01 00:00' AND DateTime<'2017-07-01 00:00' THEN 1 END) AS June
,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateTime>='2017-07-01 00:00' AND DateTime<'2017-08-01 00:00' THEN 1 END) AS July
,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateTime>='2017-08-01 00:00' AND DateTime<'2017-09-01 00:00' THEN 1 END) AS August
FROM CallRecords
WHERE CallReason = 'Appetite Question'
GROUP BY ReasonDetail
```

Comment: That's excellent and worked perfectly.  You are, however, missing the "AND" clause between the DateTime parameters. If you update your answer, I'll select it.